# Explicit types in Request Body not showing up in Swagger (NestJS)

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I am working with Swagger and NestJs. I have the following API endpoint in my controller.

```
@ApiTags('test')
@Controller('test')
export class TestController {
   @Put()
   async create(
       @Body('test') test: {
           name: string,
           age: number
       }): Promise<Foo> {
           return await this.testService.creat(test);
       }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately swagger doesn't pick up the inline type definition (or the body parameter in the first place). If I replace the inline definition with a class with `@ApiProperty()` annotations it works. However, I want to find a way *without* using Classes.

Is there a way or do I have to use classes here?

I also tried using the `ApiBody()` annotation, however that only adds a "Request Body required" field without the Type definition in swagger (see below)

[image: swagger]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you use a class to represent the body?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel That would work, but I want to avoid using classes here and see if there is a way that only utilizes inline type definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the complete schema inside the **@ApiBody()** tag. However this will only increase your work of managing this along with the actual @Body() tag.

```
@ApiTags('test')
@ApiBody({
            schema: {
                properties: {
                    'name': { type: 'string' },
                    'age': { type: 'number' }
                }
            }
         })
@Controller('test')
export class TestController {
   @Put()
   async create(
       @Body('test') test: {
           name: string,
           age: number
       }): Promise<Foo> {
           return await this.testService.creat(test);
       }
   }
}
```

I would recommend using classes instead as suggested by Jay.